# using a limit on one table when joining two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I correctly write an sql statement using a limit and join in this case?

```
SELECT  u.userName, u.userFriends, u.userJoined, f.freindName (only 3) 
FROM    user u inner join friends f ON u.userId = f.addedUserId 
WHERE   u.userId=1 
AND     f.userId=1
```

I tried

```
SELECT  u.userName, u.userFriends, u.userJoined, group_concat(f.freindName) 
FROM    user u inner join friends f ON u.userId = f.userId 
WHERE   u.userId = 1 and f.addedUserId = 1 
GROUP   by u.userName limit 5 /* but this does not work */
```

Can you help with the limiting the `f.freindName to 3`

```
'gid'  | 'userName'  | 'userId' |   'userFriends'   |'userJoined'
-------|-------------|----------|-------------------|--------------
'1'    | 'Jason'     | '1'      |   '5'             |'14-Aug-2014'


'gid'  | 'friendName'|  'thisUserId'    |'addedUserId'
-------|-------------|------------------|-----------------
'1'    | 'James'     |  '2'             |'1'
'2'    | 'Lars'      |  '3'             |'1'
'3'    | 'Kirk'      |  '4'             |'1'
'4'    | 'Rob'       |  '5'             |'1'
'5'    | 'Dave'      |  '5'             |'1'
```

Comment: You maybe have syntax error in `group_concat(f.freindName)`, it should be `group_concat(f.friendName)` (or whatever your field name is actually)

Comment: Thats ok. Its a typo. Typed in a hurry.

Comment: replace limit 5 to limit 0,5 => from first record to 4 record totally we will be getting 5 records

Comment: Are friends users? If so, `friends` should be a linking table and `friendName` should really be coming from another `JOIN` to `users`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that the tables users and friends are joined by the columns userId and addedUserId. And I assume further that you want a list of three friends of the user with the `userId = 1`.

You can use a derived table by using a subselect to get the desired result:

```
SELECT  u.userName, u.userFriends, u.userJoined, group_concat(f.friendName) 
FROM    user u 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        userId,
        friendName
    FROM
        friends
    LIMIT 3
) f
ON u.userId = f.addedUserId 
WHERE   u.userId = 1
GROUP   by u.userName
```

should work.

Comment: This may not work since the first three friends are not related with the user 1

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work. One small correction you need to make is remove the `f.` before `f.userId` in the sub query. I'm not an expert at sql, but it worked when I removed that. Otherwise, I used to get unknown column in field list.

Comment: @jmenezes Yes that was a typo by copy and paste. I've corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you are looking for. I think there is some problems with the field names (for instance `f.freindName` instead of `f.friendname`) but fixing that, This should work

```
SELECT  u.userName, u.userFriends, u.userJoined, f.freindName 
FROM    user u inner join friends f ON u.userId = f.userId 
   (SELECT  DISTINCT f.freindName 
    FROM    user u2 inner join friends f2 ON u2.userId = f2.userId
    WHERE u2.userId = u.userId
    LIMIT 3) as f
WHERE   u.userId=1
```